# commitAllowingStateLoss on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have an `IllegalStateException` on showing a `DialogFragment` :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

i know why its happening but i want to using **commitAllowingStateLoss** on showing dialog by overriding DialogFragment `show` function :

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    mDismissed = false;
    mShownByMe = true;
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit(); //replace it by commitAllowingStateLoss
}
```

but i don't access to `mDismissed` and `mShownByMe` variables , how can i access those variables to modify them as it's parent did.

Comment: IMO, `mDismissed` and `mShownByMe` can be ignored when overriding `show(FragmentManage, String)`. I cannot say that it is totally safe to do it. There are some internal handling of `mDismissed` when `mShownByMe` is `false` and `mDismissed` is by default `false`. Ignoring them seems not to impact the internal handling at all.

Answer (score 55):

I think to prevent throwing `IllegalStateException` on `DialogFragment` might be better to use :

```
 YourDialogFragment dialogFragment = new YourDialogFragment();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(dialogFragment, YourDialogFragment.TAG_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

instead of using `show()` on `DialogFragment`.

Comment: But what about the internal flag changes (` mDismissed = false;` and `mShownByMe = true;`), that won't be updated?

Comment: @Vall0n use vuhung3990 answer for that, it's better for saving state case

Answer (score 13):

The solution about commitAllowingStateLoss works if your DialogFragment has no state to save, otherwise they will be lost like the function name told. But I think in most cases we have state to save, that is the major benefit of DialogFragment: Android recreate it and maintains its state automatically.

A better solution would be to check if the recreate process done, if not then return to caller, which is either an Activity or a FragmentActivity, it should call mark it and call the show function again later in its onPostResume() or onResumeFragments() callback, which we can make sure all fragments are recreated.

Here is an overridden show() from a subclass of DialogFragment:

```
public boolean show(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
   if (fragmentManager.isStateSaved()) return false;
   show(fragmentManager, tagName);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution than accepted one by Arash GM since this allows DialogFragment to keep internal states.

Answer (score 13):

Origin dialog fragment

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    mDismissed = false;
    mShownByMe = true;
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit(); //replace it by commitAllowingStateLoss
}
```

I don't know `mDismissed`, `mShownByMe` variables used for, so should be better if override `show(FragmentManager, String)` method of DialogFragment and it works fine with me

```
override fun show(manager: FragmentManager?, tag: String?) {
    if (manager?.isDestroyed == false && !manager.isStateSaved) {
      super.show(manager, tag)
    }
  }
```

`isStateSaved` available from appcompat >= 26.0.0 or androidx

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party but hopefully it will help others in the future.
The reason this issue occurs is the DialogFragment.show() is called while the Activity is in at most in stopped state, that usually happens due to us developers trying to show the dialog as a response to an API call failure or something similar, and the user puts the app in the background, which then causes the DialogFragment.show() to get called when the activity has stopped.

To work around that we can do something really simple, we create a LiveData that holds the instance of the dialog, then, we let the activity/fragment observe the LiveData and if there's a value we just show the dialog.
Now this is going to work since LiveData only sends events to observers when the lifecycle is at least started, so the dialog is guaranteed to be shown when the Activity/Fragment is at least in started state.

From documentation of LiveData.observe -

> Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.
> The observer will only receive events if the owner is in Lifecycle.State.STARTED or Lifecycle.State.RESUMED state (active).

This is how the code looks like -

In your Fragment/Activity create a LiveData -

```
private val dialogLiveData = MutableLiveData<DialogFragment?>()
```

Next we'll observe the LiveData -

Fragment -

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    dialogLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it?.isAdded?.not() == true) {
            it.show(childFragmentManager, "dialog")
        }
    }
}
```

Activity -

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dialogLiveData.observe(this) {
        if (it?.isAdded?.not() == true) {
            it.show(supportFragmentManager, "dialog")
        }
    }
}
```

now when we want to show the dialog we're simply going to do -

```
fun showDialog() {
    dialogLiveData.value = DialogFragment()
}
```

then when we want to dismiss the dialog this is what we're going to do -

```
fun dismissDialog() {
    val dialog = dialogLiveData.value
    dialog?.let {
        if (dialog.isAdded) {
            if (dialog.lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED).not()) {
                dialogLiveData.value?.dismissAllowingStateLoss()
            } else {
                dialogLiveData.value?.dismiss()
            }
        }
        dialogLiveData.value = null
    }
}
```

Note: The LiveData is better to hold inside the VM, otherwise the DialogFragment's instance could get lost upon screen rotations